# Scala iterating through 2 collections and finding matches

Tags: scala

I have 2 collections: `a` is a sequence of Scala objects of `class C`. `b` is a sequence of strings. `C`  has a string field, `name`, that could possibly match an item in `b`. What I want is to loop through `a` and find all `c.name` that matches with one of the item in `b`. How do I do this in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterating through both a and b can get expensive because one loop nested inside another yields O(n^2) time. If b is sufficiently large, you probably want to make it into a Set first to bring this down to O(n).

```
val bSet = b.toSet;
a.filter(c => b.contains(c.name))
```

I would read this as "Apply the following filter to a: for each item c in a, include it in the result if and only if the name of c is in b."

Comment: You my friend is a rockstar! Thanks,

Comment: If b is sufficiently large, you probably want to make it into a Set first, e.g.:

    val bSet = b.toSet; a.filter(c => b.contains(c.name))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Alex but why make it a Set first and define sufficiently large.

Comment: Because `contains` on a `Set` is fast (`O(log n)`), while it is slow on general collections (`O(n)`).

Comment: @AlexCruise Thanks for calling attention to that. The original answer said to make it a set but didn't say how or why.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the equivalent for loop with yield.

```
for(c <- a if b.contains(c.name)) yield c.name
```